# Does this Boltzmann-factor-included metric relate to some known physics phenomena?

Tags: general-relativity, statistical-mechanics, gravity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

When I tried to map the motion of a constant-speed particle with speed $v$ and central force magnitude $k(r)$ to a space-time metric, it turns out the metric is in the form

$$d\lambda^2=-\alpha^2 dt^2 + \Phi^2(dr^2+r^2d\varphi^2)$$

where the metric tensor
$$\alpha^2 = 1-e^{-K/v^2}$$
$$\Phi^2=e^{-K/v^2}(1-e^{-K/v^2})$$
$K\equiv\int_0^r k(s)ds$

seems to include Boltzmann factors. I am wondering if this relates to any interesting less-known metric?

Thanks.